# Flattening schedule data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have searched over and over again, but just don't know how to word it.  Please forgive me if this has been asked.

I have schedule data that I need to "flatten".  It looks like this :

```
DATE  START   END   CODE
10/1  0700    1530  WORK    -- encompasses the entire shift of the employee
10/1  1015    1030  BREAK
10/1  1200    1230  LUNCH
10/1  1400    1415  BREAK
```

I need it to look like the following (basically removing overlaps and creating contiguous segments):

```
DATE  START   END   CODE
10/1  0700    1015  WORK
10/1  1015    1030  BREAK
10/1  1030    1200  WORK
10/1  1200    1230  LUNCH
10/1  1230    1400  WORK
10/1  1400    1415  BREAK
10/1  1415    1530  WORK
```

I cannot seem to find any sensible way to do this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like a time table (like a calendar table, but for times) would be in order here.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for responding.  I am not sure how that would work.  The "WORK" segment is arbitrary.  And the times are not all on expected boundaries (they can be any time).

Comment: Difficult. You have to determine a minumum amount of time that cant be split (15 min in these data, but maybe min?), then unpivot the start-end pairs into minutes, and then re-pivot the results.

Comment: _"I cannot seem to find any sensible way to do this."_ Did you find any non-sensible-seeming ones? ;-) If so, what were they? That way, readers don't repeat them to you.

Comment: @underscore_d I could do a ridiculous looping solution, but one of our coding standards prohibits that.  The below solution looks pretty fantastic though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks pretty complex as it is, due to me having to make the tally in the SQL as well, however, I suggest making a persisted object for this. Also, as you want your times to overlap, I have to adjust the values the final `SELECT`. Anyway, this appears to work:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ([Date] date,
                            [Start] char(4),
                            [End] char(4),
                            Code varchar(5));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Date,
                           Start,
                           [End],
                           Code)
VALUES ('20190110', '0700', '1530', 'WORK'),
       ('20190110', '1015', '1030', 'BREAK'),
       ('20190110', '1200', '1230', 'LUNCH'),
       ('20190110', '1400', '1415', 'BREAK');
GO
--Create a Time Table on the fly
--First some NULL values
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
--Now a Tally
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (1440) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4),
--And finally some formatting cause
TimeTable AS(
    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(MINUTE,T.I,'00:00'),108),':','') AS [Time]
    FROM Tally T),
--Put into Groups
Grps AS(
    SELECT YT1.Date,
           TT.Time,
           ISNULL(YT2.Code,YT1.Code) AS Code,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT1.[date] ORDER BY TT.[Time]) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT1.[date],ISNULL(YT2.Code,YT1.Code) ORDER BY TT.[Time]) AS Grp,
           MIN(YT1.[Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY YT1.[date]) AS DayStart,
           MAX(YT1.[End]) OVER (PARTITION BY YT1.[date]) AS DayEnd
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT1
         JOIN TimeTable TT ON YT1.[Start] <= TT.Time
                          AND YT1.[End] >= TT.Time
         LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT2 ON YT1.Date = YT2.Date
                                   AND YT2.[Start] <= TT.Time
                                   AND YT2.[End] >= TT.Time
                                   AND YT2.Code != 'Work'
    WHERE YT1.Code = 'WORK')
SELECT G.[Date],
       MIN([Time]) + CASE WHEN G.Code = 'Work' AND MIN(Time) != G.DayStart THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS StartTime,
       MAX([Time]) + CASE WHEN G.Code = 'Work' AND MAX(Time) != G.DayEnd THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EndTime,
       G.Code
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.Date,
         G.Code,
         G.Grp,
         G.DayStart,
         G.DayEnd
ORDER BY G.Date,
         StartTime;


GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa144b116c48addc8d81a91fa2f1a520)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this!  I think I can make this work!  Looking at this I realize how mediocre I am at SQL.  Cheers!

Comment: Great solution Larnu. +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that first builds a list of all the times, using a UNION for the start and end times.

Then in a second CTE uses LEAD to calculate the end time from the next record.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT [date], [start], [code]
    FROM timeregistration
    UNION
    SELECT [date], [end], 'WORK'
    FROM timeregistration
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT [date], [start], [code],
    LEAD([start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY [start]) AS [end]
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT [date], [start], [end], [code]
FROM CTE2
WHERE [end] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [date], [start];
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/MCG12442)